# Reading from an Input File to an Integer Array

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I'm currently coding a project in Java that will take an input file and read it into several parallel arrays. There are several restrictions--we can't use array lists, files must be read using Scanner. After reading it into the arrays, there are a few other steps that I need to code, but I have hit a hangup.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    final int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    int choice;
    int i, variableNumber;
    String[] customerName = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int[] customerID = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    String[] os = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];
    String[] typeOfProblem = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int[] turnAroundTime = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];

    readFile(customerName, customerID, os, typeOfProblem, turnAroundTime);

}

public static void readFile(String[] customerName, int[] customerID, String[] os, String[] typeOfProblem, int[] turnAroundTime) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File hotlist = new File("hotlist.txt");
    int i = 0;

    if (!hotlist.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("The input file was not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(hotlist);
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        customerName[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(customerName[i]);
        customerID[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
        os[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
        typeOfProblem[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
        turnAroundTime[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("This is only a test." + customerName[1] + "\n" + customerID[1] + "\n"
                        + os[1] + "\n" + typeOfProblem[1] + "\n" + turnAroundTime[1]);
}
```

When I try to run the above code, it fails with the following errors:

```
run:
Mike Rowe
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at mckelvey_project3.McKelvey_Project3.readFile(McKelvey_Project3.java:70)
    at mckelvey_project3.McKelvey_Project3.main(McKelvey_Project3.java:33)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The contents of the hotlist.txt file are as follows:

```
Mike Rowe
1
Windows DOS
Too Much ASCII Porn
3
Some Guy
2
Windows 10
Too Much Windows
200
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! By the way, all the System.out statements are test statements as I was trying to debug my code. I've isolated the error to specifically

```
customerID[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
```

and similarly

```
turnAroundTime[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
```

but can't figure out why those statements aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) it only consume the `int`, and it leaves any trailing whitespace or newline there. Instead you might use something like,

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(hotlist);
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    customerName[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(customerName[i]);
    String custId = inputFile.nextLine();
    customerID[i] = Integer.parseInt(custId);
    os[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
    typeOfProblem[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
    String turnAround = inputFile.nextLine();
    turnAroundTime[i] = Integer.parseInt(turnAround);
    i++;
}
```

And I get (with your code / file),

```
Mike Rowe
Some Guy
This is only a test.Some Guy
2
Windows 10
Too Much Windows
200
```

Comment: So can input files only be read as Strings (practically speaking)?

Comment: It's not a great idea to mix reading by lines and reading by other things.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're not setting a proper delimiter. After initialising the Scanner do `inputFile.useDelimiter("\n")` to set the delimiter to a line-break - the default is whitespace.

You can then read a String using `inputFile.next()` and an int using `inputFile.nextInt()` without any problems.

Comment: I entered this into my code right after the 
**scanner inputFile = new Scanner(hotlist);**
but I still receive the same error.

Comment: Also (unless I'm mistaken), using nextLine basically tells Java that the delimiter should be a new line by default.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the modification works - I've tried it out. The only thing I can think of is that you might be using Windows in which case the delimiter might need to be changed to `"\r\n"`

Comment: Okay, so I tried what you suggested and added the \r to the previous code, but to no avail.

**Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(hotlist);                             
inputFile.useDelimiter("\r\n");**